# Does piping affect operations with sqrt function?

Tags: r, pipe, tidyverse

I was doing some calculations and I noticed that when I add pipes it outputs a wrong result. It is the first time I encounter this and I would like to know why it happens to avoid this situation in the future.

```
# Making the operations separately gives the correct result.
0.58*(1-0.58) # 0.2436
sqrt(0.2436) # 0.4935585

# Adding all calculations in the same line works.
sqrt(0.58*(1-0.58)) # 0.4935585

# Use %>% doesn't give the right result.
0.58*(1-0.58) %>% sqrt() # 0.375883

# The issue doesn't happen when in a df or tibble
tibble(a = c(0.2436)) %>% 
  mutate(b = sqrt(a))
    #  A tibble: 1 × 2
    #      a     b
    #   <dbl> <dbl>
    # 1 0.244 0.494
```

Thank you,

Comment: the wrong one is doing `sqrt(1 - 0.58) * 0.58` see the note in `?magrittr::\`%>%\``: `special attention is advised when using non-magrittr operators in a pipe-chain (⁠+, -, $,⁠ etc.), as operator precedence will impact how the chain is evaluated. In general it is advised to use the aliases provided by magrittr.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `?Syntax`, you'll see that subtraction is higher precedence than pipes, and pipes are higher precedence than multiplication.

So in this expression:

```
0.58 * (1 - 0.58) %>% sqrt()
```

1 - 0.58 is evaluated to 0.42. Then 0.42 is piped to `sqrt()`. Then the result is multiplied by 0.58.

```
sqrt(0.42) * 0.58
[1] 0.375883
```

You can avoid it by wrapping the left-hand side in parentheses:

```
(0.58*(1-0.58)) %>% sqrt(.)
[1] 0.4935585
```

Answer (score 1):

It's happening due to operator precedence. And as always, using parenthesis can save from such unexpected things.

```r
library(magrittr)

(0.58*(1-0.58)) %>% sqrt()
#> [1] 0.4935585


# here multiplication is evaluated after piping.
0.58*(1-0.58) %>% sqrt()
#> [1] 0.375883

# so the above is same as doing this
((1-0.58) %>% sqrt()) * 0.58
#> [1] 0.375883
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>